# How to show an Array Return in Model to a View in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My model:

```
function get_client() {
$data['latestproblem'] = $this->db->select('hero,client,catprob,action,created_at')->where('client', $client)->order_by('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('histprob')->result();
$data['stats'] = $this->db->where('client', $client)->where('catprob', 'HEADSET TIDAK BERFUNGSI')->count_all_results('histprob');
return $data;
}
```

My controller

```
$this->skejuler_m->get_client();
```

My view:

```
echo $stats;
```

I got error *Undefined variable: stats*.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Try to return multiple queries result like this

```
$data['latestproblem'] = $this->db->select('hero,client,catprob,action,created_at')->where('client', $client)->order_by('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('histprob')->result();
$data['stats'] = $this->db->where('client', $client)->where('catprob', 'HEADSET TIDAK BERFUNGSI')->count_all_results('histprob');
return $data;
```

In your view use `json_decode()` to show your data

```
foreach(json_decode($latestproblem) as $row){

   echo $row->hero;
   echo $row->client;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it shows the same result as mine.
I have another question related to this, how my Controller look like then.. I need to show: stats in a View. I tried echo $stats but Undefined variable: stats. Thanks..

Comment: $this->skejuler_m->get_client();

It was JSONed because I used it to call in Ajax. But now I need it to show in a View as a php variable.

Comment: @W.Wan I got your point. To resolve the problem you have to add specific part of your ajax code part, controller and view also in your question.

Comment: And the second thing is if you are getting data from AJAX you can't handle in with PHP foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks in advance, I just adjusted my question. Please.. And sorry for changing the question majorly, my previous question was out of what I actually wanted. And please also change you question.. It still related.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to informed you that I have solved for the Ajax. The current problem is how to show an array return in model to a view. And please check my edited previous comment..

Comment: array is returning directr from  controller to view?

Comment: Not sure as I am new in CI, Array is in Model as I explained in my edited question

Comment: I have solved this by echoing the variable to `$myControllerName['stats']; Thanks